# Resolving service bus dependency. MassTransit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector, masstransit

The simplest way to publish a message from a controller is to have a registration code in **Global.asax.cs**:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_Start() {
        Bus.Initialize(sbc => {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/commands_webui");
        });
    }
}
```

and calling code in a controller like that:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller {
    public ActionResult AddOrderLine(OrderLine input) {
        var command = SOME_OO_MAPPER<AddOrderLineCommand>(input).Map();

        Bus.Instance.Publish<AddOrderLineCommand>(command);
        return View();
    }
}
```

1. Does resolving the **MassTransit** bus dependency with **SimpleInjector** (or with any other **IoC container**) have any advantages over the described approach? 
   Is it reasonable or would it only increase complexity?
2. Is it reasonable to use a **base controller** with **injected service bus instance**?
3. **MassTransit** defines its own `IServiceBus` interface. Is it normal to resolve service bus dependency via this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does resolving the MassTransit bus dependency with SimpleInjector (or
>   with any other IoC container) have any advantages over the described
>   approach? Is it reasonable or would it only increase complexity?

I would say that you should always favor constructor injection over using the Bus directly as an [Ambient Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx). Using constructor injection has the advantage that it makes it really clear what the class'es dependencies are. I would even prevent using a `Bus` class or `IServiceBus` abstraction from the MassTransit directly in your code, but instead define your own abstraction (even if it is the same) and register a proxy implementation that maps directly to `MassTransit`. Your message bus should be an implementation detail and your application should not have to take a dependency on it. This way you adhere to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), which allows you to decouple your core application logic from any used 3rd party libraries.

Using constructor injection does not increase complexity; your class has the same number of dependencies. The big difference is, that this is more flexible and transparent.

> Is it reasonable to use a base controller with injected service bus
>   instance?

Base classes are a code smell by many and I would even say its an anti-pattern in case they are used to contain a set of commonly used dependencies. They try to hide the fact that a class needs too many dependencies, without solving the root issue, i.e. a [Single Responsibility Violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Prevent using base classes like this, because it will make these violations stick out like a sore thumb.

> MassTransit defines its own IServiceBus interface. Is it normal to
>   resolve service bus dependency via this type?

As I said above, prevent your application code from taking a dependency on the Masstransit library itself. This introduces a vendor lock-in. Your application code (except for your Composition Root) shouldn't have to know anything about the external libraries that it uses. This holds for logging libraries, DI libraries, message bus libraries; you name it. Doing so conforms to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) that states that the client should define the abstraction. And with Dependency Injection it is really easy (and pleasurable) to prevent this coupling.

Comment: As I understand to resolve service bus dependency I got to introduce my own (level of abstraction) interface like `IAppServiceBus`, implement it using **MassTransit**, then register interface-implementation? Wouldn't it be a poor implementation of what **MassTransit** gives us?

Comment: @lexeme: You shouldn't see this as an extra level of abstraction. You will simply be conforming with the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) that states that it is the client that should define the abstraction. And your proxy can call the static `Bus` class directly, which removes MassTransit's `IServiceBus` abstraction from the picture, which means that you don't introduce extra layers of abstractions. Just different layers of abstractions.

Comment: Thank you and God bless you in Jesus name:)